# Flutter avoid persistent state management in bottom navigation bar

Tags: flutter, dart, state, future

I'm using the library `persistent_bottom_nav_bar` and I settled the `stateManagement` option equals to false because in a page I want to use a future builder each time that I enter the page.

The problem is that the future builder is not called anymore, or It is called but the page is still with the previous state.

This is my `PersistentTabView`:

```
PersistentTabView(
  context,
  screens: _NavScreens(),
  items: _navBarsItems(),
  confineInSafeArea: true,
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  handleAndroidBackButtonPress: true,
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
  hideNavigationBarWhenKeyboardShows: true,
  hideNavigationBar: false,
  stateManagement: false,
  decoration: NavBarDecoration(
    border: Border(top: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 0.5))
  ),
  popAllScreensOnTapOfSelectedTab: true,
  navBarStyle: NavBarStyle.style6,
),
```

In the example the first time that I enter in the page the future builder is called and the list appears. If I change screen and I go back in the previous screen the future builder is not working.

Example:
https://imgur.com/a/jJWJPvU

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem with [persistent_bottom_nav_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar)'s stateManagement option.I describe it to false it did not effect to state.So i found another solution.I was using bloc and provider in my project.I solved it with global keys i'll share my code hope it works.

```
 Map<int, GlobalKey<NavigatorState>> navigatorKeys = {
0: GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(),
1: GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(),
2: GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(),
3: GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(),
4: GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(),
         };

 late final List<Widget> _widgetOptions = 
  <Widget>[
  HomeView(companyId: 0, isDialogShow: isShow, bannerListModel: 
  bannerList, notificationModel: notificationList),
   CategoryTabView(),
     FavoritiesView(),
   BasketView(),
  ProfileView()
   ];

   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final basketProvider = Provider.of<BasketProvider>(context);
  final progressProvider = Provider.of<ProgressProvider>(context);
  final favoriteProvider = Provider.of<FavoriteProvider>(context);
  final bottomProvider = Provider.of<BottomNavBarProvider>(context);

return Scaffold(
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Image.asset(
            ImageConstants.instance.homeIcon,
            color: context.colorScheme.error,
            scale: 3,
          ),
          label: ""),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Image.asset(
            ImageConstants.instance.categoryIcon,
            scale: 3,
          ),
          label: ""),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: favoriteIcon(favoriteProvider), activeIcon: 
       favoriteIcon(favoriteProvider), label: ""),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: badgeBasket(basketProvider, false), activeIcon: 
      badgeBasket(basketProvider, true), label: ""),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Image.asset(
            ImageConstants.instance.profileIcon,
            scale: 3,
          ),
          activeIcon: Image.asset(
            ImageConstants.instance.profileRedIcon,
            scale: 3,
          ),
          label: ""),
       ],
        currentIndex: bottomProvider.selectedIndex,
        onTap: bottomProvider.onItemTapped,
       ),
      body: buildNavigator(bottomProvider),
       );
         }

   buildNavigator(BottomNavBarProvider bottomProvider) {
   return Navigator(
    key: navigatorKeys[bottomProvider.selectedIndex],
     onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
     return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => 
     _widgetOptions.elementAt(bottomProvider.selectedIndex));
     },
     );
     }
    }

     //this my provider

class BottomNavBarProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  int get selectedIndex => _selectedIndex;

  set selectedIndex(int index) {
    _selectedIndex = index;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void onItemTapped(int index) {
    selectedIndex = index;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

With global key method you can use your bottom nav bar static and you can avoid persistent state management.Hope it helps you.